# Organize entries as a spreadsheet (csv) using awk

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have information for entries (N= 1000) saved on a computer in a delimited text file/per entry ( every entry has one text file). The information recorded in the same format  as the following:

```
============
NAME: Matty Nigan
Age: 65 
Sex: M
Weight: XX
TIME: 12:31:25
Home address: XXXXX
Phone number: XXX XXX XXXX
============
```

I want to collect and organize all the data from these entries (N=1000) as the following:

```
NAME         AGE   SEX   Weight HOME Phone
===========
Matty Nigan  65     M    XX      XX    XX
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

I tried this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
source=path to the folder where the entries files are.
for i in $(cat file.txt); do # file.txt is including all the delimited text files names

 awk '
 /Name:/ {name=$2}
 /Age:/ {age=$2 }
 /Sex:/ {sex=$2}
 /Home: / {home=$3}
 /Phone:/ {phone=$3}
 BEGIN { FS=":"; print "name\t\tage\t\tsex\t\thome\t\tphone:\n---------"; }       
 {print $2,"\t\t",$3,"\t\t",$4,"\t\t",$6,"\t\t",$7;}END{ print "---------\nFile Complete" }'
' ${source}/${i}| sh > outdata.csv
done
```

Unfortunately this didn't work! I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it looks to me like the core part of your awk statement is printing the positional values instead of your saved variables like Name, Age, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    fmt="%-15s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n"
    printf fmt,"Name","Age","Sex","Weight","Home","Phone"
    print "---------"
}

{
    v=$0
    sub(/[^:]*: /, "", v)
    a[$1]=v
}

/Phone/ {
    printf fmt,a["NAME:"],a["Age:"],a["Sex:"],a["Weight:"],a["Home"],a["Phone"]
    delete a
}

END{ 
    print "---------\nFile Complete" 
}' file*
```

Using double-tabs between columns is problematic.  If there are, say, both long names and short names, then the columns could confusing end up in the the exact wrong places.  In the above, I formatted columns with given widths.  You may need to adjust the widths for best results.

Note that  `FS=":"` is also likely to cause problems.  Fields may contain colons and that would confuse the count.  This can be avoided by breaking the information on the first colon as the statements below. These statements capture all file information into an array `a`:

```
v=$0
sub(/[^:]*: /, "", v)
a[$1]=v
```

The first field is the key.  Everything after the first colon-space is the value.

A single awk command can process many files.  As above, all files matching the glob `file*` are processed.  Replace this with whatever glob matches your data files.

The above processes one person at a time.  This means that this code does not require large memory and, consequently, is suitable for large datasets.

#### Sample output

```
$ bash script.sh
Name           Age       Sex       Weight    Home      Phone     
---------
Matty Nigan    65        M         XX        XXXXX     XXX XXX XXXX
---------
File Complete
```

Comment: Fabulous!!! Kindly what is the purpose for putting "/Phone/ {" in line 12 that way?

Comment: @MJA From your sample, it appeared that the last line that we needed to process in a source file had the phone number.  So, when we see a line containting `Phone`, we are ready to print.  The construct `/Phone/ {...}` tells awk to execute what is in `{...}` only if the line contains `Phone`.

Comment: You are great. Thank you very much and I highly appreciate your help in this.

Comment: One more question please. AWK in this code is it able to read binary files?

Comment: awk might work, depending on the use, but it is __not__ designed for use on binary files.  It is likely to do unwanted things like add a newline character to the end of the file.  It is likely safer to start with a tool that is designed from the start for binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an awk constructed as below.  Builds an array with the details and prints the lot at the end.

```
awk -F: '
/^NAME/{name[c]=$2}
/^Age:/{age[c]=$2}
/^Sex:/{sex[c]=$2}
/^Weight:/{weight[c]=$2}
/^Home address:/{home[c]=$2}
/^Phone number:/{phone[c]=$2;c++}
END {
 print "NAME         AGE   SEX   Weight HOME Phone"
 print "==========="
 for(x in name) {
  printf "%-10s %3d    %s      %s %s %s\n",
    substr(name[x],2),
    age[x],
    sex[x],
    weight[x],
    home[x],
    phone[x]
 }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, it looks like the statement beginning "{print $2..." will be executed for every input record. Better to include the print in the braces following the /PHONE:/ selector. Also, were I doing it, I would place the BEGIN part at the head of the program, rather than embedded farther down as it is.

As noted in the previous comment, the print should call out name, age, sex, etc. rather than $2, $3, $4, etc.

I believe the /PHONE:/ {phone=$3} will give you trouble. As the sample data shows, the three groups of digits of the phone number, separated by spaces will appear to awk as $3 $4 $5. Thus, to gather up the whole phone number, 
/PHONE:/{phone = $3 "-" $4 "-" $5} would be more appropriate.